# Acer Aspire One D257 Laptop doesnt' restart

Tags: 11.10, acer, aspire-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Acer Aspire One D257 Laptop doesn't restart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89015/acer-aspire-one-d257-laptop-doesnt-restart)

I am using an Acer Netbook Aspire One D257. I have recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 and whenever I restart it from Ubuntu, it does not restart.

It just sleeps and I have to force shut down to use it again. While this problem does not occur if I shut down, suspend or hibernate.

Comment: dupe - flagged for closure

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and found the perfect answer here at [How to fix Netbook restart issue with Linux (Ubuntu)](http://www.expertcore.org/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=3009).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.